# Condition number of $A^TA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

if $n \times n$ full rank matrix $A$ has condition number $\kappa$, what would be the condition number of $A^TA$? Preferably If the derivation includes the following definition of $\kappa$:
$$
\kappa = \sigma_{max} / \sigma_{min}
$$
Where $\sigma$ are the non-zero singular-values of $A$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you mean the condition number defined by the Euclidean norm, i.e.
$$
\kappa = \|A\|\cdot \|A^{-1}\|
$$
Note also that $\|A\| = \|\sqrt{A^TA}\|$. Conclude that $\kappa(A^TA) = \kappa(A)^2$.

Comment: Not quite.  You forgot a square.  Also, this is assuming the operator norm induced by the Euclidean norm.  There are other matrix norms that are used in defining condition numbers.

Comment: Side note: one option for solving $Ax = b$ numerically could be to solve $A^T A x = A^T b$ using the conjugate gradient method, a method which requires the coefficient matrix to be symmetric.  However, this approach has the disadvantage that the condition number of $A^T A$ is the square of the condition number of $A$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael whoops, fixed.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. How is $||A|| . ||A^{-1}||$ is equal to $\lambda_{max}/\lambda_{min}$ ? I am trying to show that the condition number of $A^TA$ is the square of the condition number of $A$ using the eigenvalues definition of condition number.

Comment: $\|A\| \cdot \|A^{-1}\| = \lambda_{max}/\lambda_{min}$ when $A$ is symmetric, but this is not generally the case.  The condition number is *not* usually defined to be the ratio of those eigenvalues.  Can we assume that $A$ is symmetric?

Comment: Where did you see the condition number defined in this way? Perhaps we're given that $A$ is normal.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom It should be $\sigma_{max}/\sigma_{min}$ .. I fixed it in the question.. We can't assume that $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: @Hayer in that case, then notice that $\|A\| = \sigma_{max}(A)$, and that $\|A^{-1}\| = \sigma_{max}(A^{-1}) = \frac 1{\sigma_{min}(A)}$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: great! can you add the proof that $\|A\| = \|\sqrt{A^TA}\|$?

Comment: @hayer it amounts to an application of the definition of a singular value. What definition do you usually use?

Answer (score 3):

The result is true for rectangular matrices.

Let $p\geq q$ and  $A\in M_{p,q}(\mathbb{R})$ be a full column rank matrix. We consider $||A||_2=\sup \dfrac{||Ax||_2}{||x||_2}$ and $cond(A)=||A||.||A^+||$ where $A^+$ is the pseudo-inverse of $A$. Then $cond(A)^2=cond(A^TA)$ (exercise)

In particular, if we want to use the Gauss method of least squares for $Ax-b$, then we must solve $A^TAx=A^Tb$; thus the condition number of this calculation is $cond(A)^2$. Finally, if $A,b$ are known with $N$ significant digits and if $cond(A)\approx 10^k$, then $x$ is known with $N-2k$ significant digits.